# CQWP error:- The web part references an untrusted XSL file

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, site, xslt-list-view-web-part

I've created Announcement CQWP. I've deploy wsp on local site root **http://pc99** its working fine.
but when I'm trying to use it on  site **http://pc99/sites/Test/Pages/Home.aspx** It shows error:

> The web part references an untrusted XSL file. Only XSL files contained in this site's Style Library may be referenced.

[image]

my CQWP on  **http://pc99/sites/Test**  currently pointing xsl from root site  now am trying to point xsl from current site  **http://pc99/sites/Test** insted of root site.

Answer (score 3):

You could export the content query web part and open it in notepad. Then define the **MainXslLink** and **ItemXslLink** property values as `"/rootsite/subsite/style library/xsl style sheets/Xslfile name.xsl"` in the **content query web part**.

And you also could change the url of the xsl file. Make sure there is a major version of the published xsl.

There is a similar case:

[I have created my own ItemStyleCustom.xsl file, how to use it for my CQWP?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77131/i-have-created-my-own-itemstylecustom-xsl-file-how-to-use-it-for-my-cqwp)